# UIDevice class for Mac OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am trying to port one of my iOS applications to Mac OS X, and I am struggling to find the `UIDevice`-like object for OS X. I am interested in getting the name of the device, such as "MacBookAir".

**EDIT/ANSWER**
As Josh Caswell pointed out, you can use `SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName` key.

Here is the code:

```
+ (NSString *)computerName {
   return [(id)SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName(NULL, NULL) autorelease];
}
```

Comment: For those wondering: #import <SystemConfiguration/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific.h>

Comment: For ARC: return CFBridgingRelease(SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName(NULL, NULL));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Net Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001076-97283) says:

> In Mac OS X on the desktop, calling the `SCDynamicStore` function from the System Configuration framework returns the computer name so you can manipulate it like any other string. In iOS, you can obtain the same information from the name property of the `UIDevice` class.

There doesn't seem to be a single function called `SCDynamicStore` (doc bug), but you probably want [`SCDynamicStoreCopyValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStore/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008287). Looks like you get the key you need using [`SCDynamicStoreKeyCreateComputerName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreKey/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008290-CH100-DontLinkElementID_7).

EDIT: Or, even better, as you found, use the [`SCDynamicStoreCopyComputerName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008289-CH100-DontLinkElementID_2) function, found in SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific.h

Comment: Thanks Josh. I gave the code snippet in my question. You may edit your answer to include the code snippet, so others have a reference. Computer name suppose to be a simple task to find but as it turns out it's not. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for putting in the snippet -- I'll just leave it in the question, but I did add a link to the docs for that function.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.0 OSX**

Here is what I needed for a similar value to UIDevice name

iOS (swift 3.2)

```
let deviceName = UIDevice.current.name
```

OSX (swift 4.0)

```
let deviceName = Host.current().name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSHost *host = [NSHost currentHost];
NSLog(@"hostName %@",[host localizedName]);
```

you can see the mac name

Comment: Apple docs:  "..and may block for several seconds if the network is unreachable. To avoid blocking execution on the main thread, you should call this method in an Operation or Grand Central Dispatch.." on Swift 4.2:         let  host = Host.current()....

Answer (score 0):

You can try NSHost.  [Heres the class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes, but doesn't it give me names such as 'John's_MacBook'?

Answer (score 0):

With [the deprecation of `Host`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/host/), you might consider [`ProcessInfo.hostName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1417236-hostname/) as an alternative. In my case it returned:

```
ExampleHostName.local
```